# Simplifying the list for nested data frame

Tags: r, json, list, nested, combinations

Sorry I am new in R
I need to get a dataframe ready a json format. But I have trouble to put the variable back to the original format c(1,2,3,...). For example

```
library(tidyr)
x<-tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(c(1,5), c(1,5,10), c(1,2,3,20)))
View(x)
```

This shows

```
1           1              c(1, 5)
2           2              c(1, 5, 10)
3           3              c(1, 2, 3, 20)

x1<-x %>% unnest(y)
x2<-x1 %>% nest(data=c(y))
View(x2)

This shows
1           1              1 variable 
2           2              1 variable 
3           3              1 variable
```

the desired format is c(...) rather than a variable to get ready for the json data file

```
1           1              c(1, 5)
2           2              c(1, 5, 10)
3           3              c(1, 2, 3, 20)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`x$y` is a list-column of `double`s. Whereas `x2$y` is a list-column of `tibble`s.

Use `map` and `unlist` to turn the `tibble`s into `double`s.

```
library(tidyverse)

x2 %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, unlist))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x data     
#>   <int> <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [2]>
#> 2     2 <dbl [3]>
#> 3     3 <dbl [4]>
```

Alternatively, instead of `nest`ing, you can use `summarise`.

```
x1 %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(data = list(y))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x data     
#>   <int> <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [2]>
#> 2     2 <dbl [3]>
#> 3     3 <dbl [4]>
```

Comment: Dear Paul You are amazing! Problem is solved. Thank you very very much. Yuejen